# Hide the dropdown list when clicking or scrolling on outside

Tags: css, reactjs, autocomplete

I want to close my dropdown list after clicking or scrolling outside the pane. Still the dropdown box is open all time when we scrolling outside the dropdown box.. This is my code..

```
static defaultProps = { // <-- DEFAULT PROPS
          wrapperStyle: {
            display: 'inline',

             }, 
          menuStyle: {
                borderRadius: '3px',
                boxShadow: '0 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
                padding: '2px 0',
                fontSize: '90%',
                position: 'fixed',
                minWidth: '300px',
                overflow: 'auto',
                maxHeight: '250px',
                display: 'inline', 
              }  
    }
```

..............................................................

```
<ReactAutocomplete
                                name="ReferredBy"

                                items = {patientsMasterData.ReferredBy && patientsMasterData.ReferredBy.map(referredObj =>(
                                    {options:referredObj.RefName, 
                                   values:referredObj.RefID}
                                  ))
                                }

                                shouldItemRender={(item, value) => item.options.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1}
                                getItemValue={(item) => item.options}
                                renderItem={(item, highlighted) =>
                                    <div
                                    key={item.values}
                                    style={{ backgroundColor: highlighted ? '#3db4e5' : '#FFFFFF',cursor:'pointer', border:'1px solid lighten($grey-element,30%)',padding: '5px}}
                                    {item.options}</div>}
                 inputProps={{placeholder:'Select...'}}
                                menuStyle={this.props.menuStyle}
                                wrapperStyle={this.props.wrapperStyle}
                                value={this.state.value}
                          onChange{e=>this.setState({value:e.target.value})}
                                onSelect={value => this.setState({ value })}

                       />
```

& the css portion,

```
&_value1 {
              flex:2;
              white-space: normal;
              width: 100%;
              // overflow-y: auto;
              font-size: 14px;
              position: relative;
              z-index: 2;
              display: inline-block;
              input, textarea {
                width: 100%;
                min-width: 200px;
                height: 25px;
                border: 1px solid $grey-element;
                padding: 0 8px;
                font-size: 12px;   
              }
             &::after {
                position: absolute;
                right: 9px;
                top: 10px;
                content: '';
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 6px 3px 0 3px;
                border-color: $black transparent transparent transparent;
              }   }
```

How can I hide the dropdown box when scrolling outside?

Answer (score 0):

In few words: you need to add event listener when dropdown is open and make ref on your dropdown to avoid click event on your dropdown, but fire it on clicking somewhere else (and remove eventlistener here). Also you can listen for scrolling events. This is implementation example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

class Dropdown extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setWrapperRef = this.setWrapperRef.bind(this);
        this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
    };

    setWrapperRef(node) {
        this.wrapperRef = node;
    };

    handleClickOutside(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(e.target) && this.props.isOpen){
            this.props.onClose();
        }
    };

    componentDidUpdate(){
        if(this.props.isOpen){
            document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
        } else {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
        }
    }

   render(){
       return (
            <div className={"dropdown " + (this.props.isOpen ? "show" : "hide")} ref={this.setWrapperRef}>
                <CSSTransition in={this.props.isOpen} timeout={300} classNames="fadeIndown" unmountOnExit={true}>
                        {this.props.children}
                </CSSTransition>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Dropdown;
```

Comment: But I just using auto complete tag. I doubt, It seems like the above solution doesn't works in it.Or if it works how we can write it in this tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
const toggleDropdown = () => this.setState({ isDropdownOpen: !this.state.isDropdownOpen });

const closeDropdownThen = fn => (...params) => {
  this.setState({ isDropdownOpen: false });
  return fn(...params);
};
```

under the render you should define like that constant like above.  And when you use

```
       <Dropdown
            isOpen={isDropdownOpen}
            toggleDropdown={toggleDropdown}
            className={s.dropDownContainer}
            label="Export"
          >
            <DropdownItem onClick={closeDropdownThen(this.abcFunction)}>
               CSV
            </DropdownItem>
```

this is my dropDown component maybe it helps you. Best regards

Comment: Thanks, But this is in not supported in react auto complete tag.